# Simple Jquery function won't work

Tags: jquery, html

I have following jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    for(var i=1;i<4;i++) { 
        var img= ".img"+i; 
        var p= ".p"+i;
        $(img).on("click", function(){
            $(p).hide(); 
        }); 
    } 
});
```

Applied on the following html:

```
<div>
    <article>
         <h1>Over mezelf <img src='images/plus.png' class='img1'/></h1>

        <p class='p1'>Test</p>
    </article>
    <article>
         <h1>Contact <img src='images/plus.png' class='img2'/></h1>

        <p class='p2'>Test</p>
    </article>
    <article>
         <h1>Website <img src='images/plus.png' class='img3'/></h1>

        <p class='p3'>Test</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

When I click on the images, the last `<p>` disappears, it doesn't work on the other ones.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example for an explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is due to the scope of `p`. When it comes round to running the event handler code it will always use the most recent value of 'p', which in this case would be `".p3"` ([see here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue))

**Quick Fix**

You could use a closure instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++) { 
        var img= ".img" + i;
        var p = ".p" + i;
        (function(p){
            $(img).on("click", function(){
                $(p).hide();
            });
        })(p);
    }
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SUVar/)

---

**Recommended**

Personally I would prefer to change your HTML to use a common class, this will avoid the need for a loop. You can then navigate your way to the correct `p` tag...

HTML:

```
<div>
    <article>
         <h1>Over mezelf <img src='images/plus.png' class='img'/></h1>

        <p class='p1'>Test</p>
    </article>
    <article>
         <h1>Contact <img src='images/plus.png' class='img'/></h1>

        <p class='p2'>Test</p>
    </article>
    <article>
         <h1>Website <img src='images/plus.png' class='img'/></h1>

        <p class='p3'>Test</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

(note that you can have multiple classes if you still need the numbered ones for something else. e.g: `"img img1"`)

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".img").on("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("article").find("p").hide();
    });
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SUVar/1/)

Comment: `For` loops are seldom needed with jQuery events. Always best to try and roll up into a single selector if possible. I would recommend they not use unique class names as that is kind of pointless. Unique IDs and/or shared classes would make more sense (if needed at all). Adding an IIFE is complicating further something that should be trivial.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Yes I would have gone down that path, and was tempted to included it in my answer but I was undecided if it was going a bit too far considering the question

Comment: The original code needs to be printed out, then shredded and recycled! This was putting on a bandaid when amputation was needed :)

Answer (score 4):

You just need this

```
$(img).on("click", function(){
    $(this).closest('article').find('p').hide(); 
 });
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XhRPC/)

**Docs**

[`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: `For` loops are seldom needed with jQuery events. Always best to try and roll up into a single selector if possible. I would recommend they not use unique class names as that is kind of pointless. Unique IDs and/or shared classes would make more sense (if needed at all).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
 $('img').on("click", function(){
     $(this).parent().next().hide(); 
 });
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/XhRPC/1/

Comment: +1 for daring to simplify the entire problem to a single selector. This is how it should be done :)

Answer (score 1):

Milind Anantwar's answer is definitely the way to go, but here are a few more notes:

You may need the selectors to be more specific, so they are less dependent on layout changes:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/XhRPC/2/

```
$(function () {
     $('article h1 img').on('click', function(){
         $(this).closest('article').find('p').last().hide(); 
     });
});
```

This finds the closest `article` ancestor, then finds the last paragraph (`.children('p').last()` does the same thing only faster than `find` as it search only one level)

*Note: `$(function(){YOUR CODE HERE});` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){YOUR CODE HERE});`

You should not have unique class names unless you actually mean to style each element specifically. Unique identifiers belong in `id=` and shared classes belong in `class=`.

### Dynamic elements?: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/XhRPC/3/

Should you introduce dynamically loaded elements, of the same type you have shown, you can easily change it to use a delegated version of `on()`:

```
$(function () {
     $(document).on('click', 'article h1 img', function(){
         $(this).closest('article').find('p').last().hide(); 
     });
});
```

Delegated events listen at an ancestor, *then* apply the selector, *then* apply the function to any matching elements that generated the event.

The preference is to use the *first non-changing ancestor* in your DOM. Failing that (you do not show the rest of the page) you can use document which receives all bubbled events on the page.